# Python -- Reading a file and determining lowest score and person

Tags: python, list, for-loop, file-io, split

There is a file that contains the following information in the same order: LastName FirstName IDnumber score1 score2 finalScore. My objective is to determine the lowest finalScore of the entire file and the IDnumber of the student that got that score. This is what I have, but i'm not sure how to associate the IDnumber with the score.

```
scores = open('text.txt', 'w')
scores.write('Johnson Jeff 1213 91 92 94\n')
scores.write('Johnson Alan 5553 81 82 84\n')
scores.write('Johnson Bart 8973 91 82 98\n')
scores.close()
grades = open('text.txt','r')
listy = []
for i in grades:
    a = i.split()
    for j in a[3:]:
        listy.append(j)
print(min(listy))
```

Comment: Consider using a dictionary instead of a list.

Comment: if the file is pre-established can i make the file into a dictionary?

Comment: use dictionary in your for loop. use name as key and final score as value.

Comment: @user3014014 yes, I'll write an answer speaking directly to that

Answer (score 7):

Using dictionary would be very easy. But if you want to do it the way you are doing it right now, you can use `min(..)` with a custom key.

```
>>> s = ['Johnson Jeff 1213 91 92 94', 'Johnson Alan 5553 81 82 84', 'Johnson Bart 8973 91 82 98']
>>> min(s, key=lambda x: int(x.split()[5]))
'Johnson Alan 5553 81 82 84'
```

Answer (score 2):

Since I have a feeling that you are a beginner in Python,I wrote the code to be as simple as possible.
**The algorithm:**

1. Builds on the code you provided until line 6
2. Create an empty dictionary with the final scores as the key and the ids as the value
3. We create a list of all the keys
4. Order the list, and print call the dictionary with the smallest final score
5. Finally print the ID of the lowest final score

**Here's the code:**

```
    #Your Code:
    scores = open('text.txt', 'w')
    scores.write('Johnson Jeff 1213 91 92 94\n')
    scores.write('Johnson Alan 5553 81 82 84\n')
    scores.write('Johnson Bart 8973 91 82 98\n')
    scores.close()
    grades = open('text.txt','r'
    #Added code 
    IDS={}
    for line in grades:
        line_items = line.split()
        if line_items[5] in IDS:
            IDS[line_items[5]].append(line_items[2])
        else:
            IDS[line_items[5]] = [line_items[2]]
    scores = IDS.keys()
    scores = list(scores)
    scores.sort(key = int)
    print("The id of the lowest FinalScore is",IDS[scores[0]])
```

*Hope this helps :)*

Answer (score 0):

Instaed of creating a list create a dict and IDnumber as key and score list as value:

```
grades = open('text.txt','r')
dd={}
for i in grades:
    dd[i.split()[2]]=min(i.split()[3:])

min_score = min(dd, key=dd.get)
```

min_score is your answer

Answer (score 0):

You asked how to read the file to a dict, here's some code:

```
d = dict()
with open('text.txt','r') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        data = line.split(" ")
        d[data[2]] == {
            "lastName":data[0],
            "firstName":data[1],
            "score1":data[3],
            "score2":data[4],
            "finalScore":data[5]}
```

That will write your file to a dictionary `d`, then to iterate on it use `min()` with a key:

```
lowestScore = min(d, key = lambda k: d[k]['finalScore'])
#this returns the key in d with the lowest finalScore
```

Answer (score 0):

Converting to dict will work only on small files.

```
# pseudocode for huge files
with open(filename) as f:
    result_lines = []  # if many people has same score
    min_score = 100500  
    for line in f:
        score = get_score(line) # get_score should return int
        if score < min_score: 
            result_line = [line]
        elif score == min_score:
            result_line.append(line)
```